# how to use Stroryboard ViewController File in xib?

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, xib

I want to use storyboard view controller in my xib file .

for example
I have an XIB file(like Purchase_Bill) and storyboard view controller file
(like Bill_Payment),
then I want to use storyboard view controller file(like Bill_Payment) in my xib file(like Purchase_Bill).
Can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: why don't you use storyboard for your both view controllers?

Comment: i can use but drawer can not be implemented so I can use xib drawer to my project

Comment: drawer? try this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tie it together with code in `-viewDidLoad` and/or actions. One way is to load the nib:

```
[self addSubview:[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibView" owner:self options:nil][0]];
```

And the same method can be used for controllers

A second and often preferable method is to use convention to load the xib.

```
[[MyXibViewController alloc] init]
```

will load from MyXibViewController.xib if it creates a nib in the bundle.

Once you have a view controller object, you can create a segue manually like

```
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"" source:self destination:toViewController];
[self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
[segue perform];
```